# Android TabLayout проблема

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Хочу реализовать TabLayout в своем приложении.
Есть n число вкладок(к примеру n=10)
Проблема: при таком количестве владок они становятся очень маленькими (скрин 1)
Вопрос: как сделать, чтоб только показывались три (т.е. один выбранный по середине и по-одному слева и справа (скрин 2))

[image] 
[image]

Comment: А чем не устраивает actionbar tabs? https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/178-urok-108-android-3-actionbar-navigatsija-taby-i-vypadajuschij-spisok.html

Comment: я его и использую. проблема в другом. вы видите разницу между тем, что у меня есть(скрин 1) и тем, чего я хочу добиться(скрин 2)?

Comment: @Murad, насколько мне известно, из коробки такое не настроить. Придётся писать собственную View. Это, обычно, долго и не очень просто, засим рассмотрите возможность сделать просто прокручивающиеся табы (атрибут `scrollable` у `TabLayout`)

Comment: я примерно и рассчитывал, что будет что-то на подобие scrollable. буду делать!